# Cronbach's Alpha and reliability tests translation from SPSS to R

Tags: r, spss

I am translating some SPSS code to R and I'm trying to find out where there is a efficient way to translate following piece of code:

```
RELIABILITY
  /VARIABLES=var_1 var_2 var_3
  /SCALE('var_skill') ALL
  /MODEL=ALPHA
  /STATISTICS=DESCRIPTIVE SCALE CORR COV
  /SUMMARY=TOTAL MEANS VARIANCE.
```

This gives me following output in SPSS: Cronbach's Alpha, Item Statistics, Inter-item Correlation Matrix, Inter-Item Covariance Matrix, Item Means & Variance, Item Scale Statistics and mean, variance and stddev of the scale.

I managed to get similar results with the alpha command from 'psych' package in R, as well as with cor() and cov() for correlation and covariance. The problem is, I can't find a way to include "/SCALE('var_skill') ALL" in my R code.
Is there a specific way to do that?

Comment: What is "/SCALE('var_skill') ALL"? I know R but not SPSS

Comment: It defines a scale for the analysis. So the reliability of the scale of the variable 'var_skill' would be analyzed.

Comment: I am sorry but what does "defines a scale for the analysis" mean? There are different scales, like z scores with mean 0 and sd1

Comment: As I understand it (I'm also not familiar with SPSS), this line creates a new scale var_skill that is comprised of all the items declared in the VARIABLES=. So the items var_1, var_2 and var_3 all have the same 7-step-Likert scale (1=do not agree at all & 7=agree completely) and make up the new scale var_skill on which the reliability test is done.

Comment: I have access to SPSS and run your code. The code does not create a new variable "var_skill" in the dataset. So you are not missing anything here. So if you have all the results you need, why caring about that bit of code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I got your problem right, you might want to define the scale beforehand which is not necessary like schwantke suggests. This code should give you alpha based on the five items(I1 through I5) of your dataframe (df):

```
alpha(df[c("I1","I2","I3","I4","I5")], check.keys=TRUE)
```

Technically, it should do what you want and give you alpha for all five items because everything that "/SCALE" does is group your items under a name of your choice (which you could define in SPSS in the first screen of the user interface). If you leave out the "/SCALE" command, SPSS would use all selected items anyway. So all you could do, is group your scale like so:

```
scale1<-df[c("I1","I2","I3","I4","I5")]
alpha(scale1, check.keys=TRUE)
```

If you chose other options than ALL in "/SCALE('var_skill') ALL" that might be a different story but in several years of psychological research I never needed that option.